# multiple box per 5 line

Tags: tables, column-width

I think I've reached my solution on how to have 3 box each line, for 5 lines. this is an example.

```
\begin{document}
\tcbset{colback=red!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,size=small,
fonttitle=\bfseries,width=6.3cm,box align=top,
nobeforeafter}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=flush center,halign=flush center]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=flush left,halign=flush left]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=flush right,halign=flush right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\\%-----termina una fila di box
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=center,halign=center]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=left,halign=left]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\

\end{document}
```

But I would also control the higtest of the box, because I will put inside a box the text without knowing its exact highest. I would that the box will stop to show the text when it is at the end of the box.
In other word: I would set the exact hightest and width of box, but I  just find the”width” parameter, not the parameterb for exact hightest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very uncleared on what you want to achieve. There is indeed a `height` key you can set in `tcolorbox`. And here is an example that show maximum height of 5 lines of boxes in default margin of report document class.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=red!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,size=small,
fonttitle=\bfseries,width=0.333\textwidth,box align=top,height=3.85cm,nobeforeafter}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{-\topskip}\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=flush center,halign=flush center]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works. 
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works. 
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=flush left,halign=flush left]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=flush right,halign=flush right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\\\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=center,halign=center]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=left,halign=left]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\\\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\\\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\\\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes! it works! now i will use it and I'll tune it